# C macro concatenation to create a struct

Tags: c, macros, struct, concatenation

I'm trying to create a macro to automate the creation of accessors for different types of variables in a simple "database" in C.  This is done via a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int var1;
    long var2;
    double var3;
    int var4;
} dataNames_t;
```

But to automate things, I'd like to create a bunch of macros to mimic overloading of functions so I don't have to have individual `getInt`, `getBool`, `getLong`, etc functions.  We do this fairly often so we can very quickly add entries to long lists of very similar things.  This way we don't have to modify 5 places in a file to add an entry.  However, I can't seem to figure it out for a structure.

```
#define DATA_LIST        \
  DM(var1, int),         \
  DM(var2, long),        \
  DM(var3, double),      \
  DM(var4, int)

#define DM(y, z)    z y;

/* create data structure from the macro */
typedef struct {
    DATA_LIST
} dataNames_t;
```

This struct should evaluate to the first one, but something's not working right.

```
#define DM(y, z)    z y##;
```

doesn't work, either.

Comment: Incidentally, in C, what is the advantage of getters and setters?

Comment: The easy way to diagnose preprocessing errors is to run your source through just the preprocessor and see what comes out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the comma at the end of each `DM(...)` in your `DATA_LIST`; your struct is effectively expanding to:

```
typedef struct {
    int var1;,
    long var2;,
    double var3;,
    int var4;
} dataNames_t;
```

Change your `DATA_LIST` to:

```
#define DATA_LIST       \
  DM(var1, int)         \
  DM(var2, long)        \
  DM(var3, double)      \
  DM(var4, int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-E` flag in gcc if you want to see the output of the preprocessor. This can be very useful in debugging macros.

However in this case, the problem is the commas on each line here:

```
  DM(var1, int),         \
  DM(var2, long),        \
  DM(var3, double),      \
  DM(var4, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the comma after every `DM()` in your `DATA_LIST` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas from DATA_LIST:

```
#define DATA_LIST        \
  DM(var1, int),         \
  DM(var2, long),        \
  DM(var3, double),      \
  DM(var4, int)
```